# Java on raspberry starting slow?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

I installed Java on my Raspberry Pi and it starts up really slow. Why is this happening?

```
# time java
..
real    0m1.356s
user    0m1.190s
sys     0m0.110s
```

**edit:** I was comparing to a Hello World c++ binary and it took 0m0.001s. Why is c++ binaries so much faster?

Comment: Just making sure... you're talking about a Raspberry Pi, right?

Comment: How fast did you think it should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two limiting factors about the startupspeed:

1. Software

   1. The distribution, you have installed. There are distributions out there, which has to emulate some operations (soft-ABI)
   2. The Java-Version
   3. The application, you want wo start
2. Hardware

   1. The raspberry pi is SLOW, it has only 256MB (512MB) of RAM. This is sharedwith the grafic processor (most ~50MB or more)
   2. There is only one CPU with ~800MHTz
   3. The CPU is an ARM (which is slower than an x86) *)

Th first time I started Java (a tomcat web server), it needed around 5min to start. On my PC, it needs ~15sec

**update**
The updated question gives the answer.
You compare a native compiled hello world with the startup of a complete virtual maschine.

I think, you will always get an increditable worse start performance for (the first) starting Java-application.

The second java-process may use shared memory with the first one, so a second application may start faster.

*) I think it is slower, I have no benchmark about it

Answer (score 4):

Raspberry Pi has a much slower processor than your computer so everything on it is going to run much slower than what you usually see.

EDIT*

I would argue that C++ will be much faster because of the initial overhead that Java has in order to run. You need to account for the time it takes for the JVM to start as well as the fact that the C++ program is already compiled while the Java program is not.

It is important to note, however, that C++ is not always faster than Java. The JIT (just in time) compiler that is used by the JVM helps optimize your code while it is running.

Comment: I was comparing to a Hello World c++ binary and it took 0m0.001s. Why is c++ binaries so much faster?

Comment: Thank you for adding your edit of the test you did. It makes the question more clear.

Comment: doesn't javac compile the program and then java comes to run the binary? why does it need jvm to run anyway?

Comment: It seems you may have a very limited or new understanding of Java. I suggest you read more bout Java here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info. Javac turns your code into Java Byte code which the JVM later turns into binary. This is so the code you write in Java can be run on any machine that supports Java not just the one architecture you have written it for.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. is there a way to compile java to binary?

Comment: The main benefit of Java is the optimizing Jus-In-Time compiler. The Virtual Maschine executes the ByteCode. After a amount of runs (I think 10000 invocations for a method, this method is compiled into native code. The JVM creates some statistice while running your code. The compiled native code may become faster than native code because of the knowledge of the runtime.

Comment: Java to native compiler? => Yes an no. There was a project (Gnu Java Compiler) but it never became important, because of the HotSpot JIT in Java. Java is really good for long running processes. If you need a fast start time, use another tool. Or try  http://martiansoftware.com/nailgun/ (I haven't tried it yet, because I write heavy Java Server application. Startup time is not that important to me)

Answer (score -1):

Actually I didn't want to add an answer, as the existing answers are perfectly explaining your apple and pear comparison.

However, I think the fact that the JVM implementation has a [significant impact on performance](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/comparing_jvms_on_arm_linux) needs more visibility.

I came here myself, as my Spring application needed 100 seconds to start. After switching from OpenJDK-8 to Oracle's Hotspot, startup took only 15 seconds. Hotspot for ARM is included in Raspbian:

```
apt-get install oracle-java8-jdk
```